# Issue with linkText while clicking on hyperlink

Tags: selenium-webdriver

`html is:<a href="http.someurl.com" class="tango">abc news</a>`I want to click on 'abc news' link. I am using linkText as locator but it is not working.Could anyone let me know why linkText is not working in this case?I only want to use linkText as locator no other locator

By.linkText("abc news")).click();

Comment: Please expand your question by providing a sample of the html and a snippet of your code it will make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: can anyone provide input on this?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use wait before clicking on an element:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("abc news")));

Then,try to clcik on an element.
driver.findElement(By.linkText("abc news")).click();

Comment: I tried but no luck.Same locator used to work on same html around 2 month back but now it is not working.Any idea why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use linkText or xpath: (By.xpath("//a[text()='abc news']")) & By.linkText("abc news")